# Set a converter for ModelMapper only once

Tags: java, spring

I have the follwoing code for converting an object of class `User` to its DTO of type `GetUserDto`:

```
public GetUserDto convertToDto(User user) {
    Converter<User, GetUserDto> converter = context -> {
        User source = context.getSource();
        GetUserDto target = new GetUserDto();
        target.setDescription(source.getDescription());
        target.setId(source.getId());
        target.setName(source.getName());
        target.setImageId(source.getImageId());
        return target;
    };
    modelMapper.createTypeMap(User.class, GetUserDto.class).setConverter(converter);
    return modelMapper.map(user, GetUserDto.class);
}
```

It works fine for the first time, but the subsequent calls to `convertToDto` throws:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: A TypeMap already exists for class com.boot.cut_costs.model.User and class com.boot.cut_costs.dto.user.ExtendedGetUserDto`

I found some other posts regarding this, one suggested to null check `TypeMap` for `modelMapper` and not to create it again if it wasn't `null`. This is not a good solution as if you have thousands of calls to this method it adds unnecessary overhead to it.

Any good solution ?

Comment: How about split converters init and convert logic? Init all your converters just once on start and just use `return modelMapper.map(user, GetUserDto.class);`

Comment: how can I init automatically at the time of creation ? It's a service component (i.e. class containing the converter is annotated with `@Service` )

Comment: E.g. specify annotation like scan package which target to package(s). Go through all classes from the package and if a class instance of Converter add the class to the mapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I found some other posts regarding this, one suggested to null check
>   TypeMap for modelMapper and not to create it again if it wasn't null.
>   This is not a good solution as if you have thousands of calls to this
>   method it adds unnecessary overhead to it.

If you look into the code of `org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.getTypeMap()`
and  `org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.createTypeMap()`, you will see that 
creating a `TypeMap` that is a higher overhead as simply invoking a method to retrieve a `TypeMap`.

Returning the object from a map if it exists is straight:

```
  public <S, D> TypeMap<S, D> getTypeMap(Class<S> sourceType, Class<D> destinationType) {
    Assert.notNull(sourceType, "sourceType");
    Assert.notNull(destinationType, "destinationType");
    return config.typeMapStore.<S, D>get(sourceType, destinationType, null);
  }
```

While the adding performs much more things.
It creates a proxy type, does a synchronized task and does some checks before  creating a `TypeMap` instance and at last it puts it in the map :

```
  private <S, D> TypeMap<S, D> createTypeMapInternal(S source, Class<S> sourceType,
      Class<D> destinationType, String typeMapName, Configuration configuration) {
    if (source != null)
      sourceType = Types.<S>deProxy(source.getClass());
    Assert.state(config.typeMapStore.get(sourceType, destinationType, typeMapName) == null,
        String.format("A TypeMap already exists for %s and %s", sourceType, destinationType));
    return config.typeMapStore.create(source, sourceType, destinationType, typeMapName,
        (InheritingConfiguration) configuration, engine);
  }
```

that invokes also :

```
  public <S, D> TypeMap<S, D> create(S source, Class<S> sourceType, Class<D> destinationType,
      String typeMapName, InheritingConfiguration configuration, MappingEngineImpl engine) {
    synchronized (lock) {
      TypeMapImpl<S, D> typeMap = new TypeMapImpl<S, D>(sourceType, destinationType, typeMapName,
          configuration, engine);
      if (configuration.isImplicitMappingEnabled()
          && ImplicitMappingBuilder.isMatchable(typeMap.getSourceType())
          && ImplicitMappingBuilder.isMatchable(typeMap.getDestinationType()))
        new ImplicitMappingBuilder<S, D>(source, typeMap, config.typeMapStore,
            config.converterStore).build();
      typeMaps.put(TypePair.of(sourceType, destinationType, typeMapName), typeMap);
      return typeMap;
    }
  }
```

So do the check if a more efficient solution  :

```
if (modelMapper.getTypeMap(User.class,GetUserDto.class) == null){
    modelMapper.createTypeMap(User.class, GetUserDto.class).setConverter(converter);
}
return modelMapper.map(user, GetUserDto.class);
```

Now, if you want really avoid unnecessary processing, you could create the TypeMap and set all converter associated to in a specific class once.

```
public void initTypeMaps(){
        modelMapper.createTypeMap(User.class, GetUserDto.class).setConverter(converterUserAndUserDto);
        modelMapper.createTypeMap(Other.class, GetOtherDto.class).setConverter(converterOtherAndOtherDto);
 ...
}
```

At last, if you have thousands of calls to this method in a short time and  you want to reduce to the maximum the overhead, don't use ModelMapper and a converter but do the mapping between two classes at hand.